# Last Posts except by category

Tags: blogger

I would like to see on the first page (Last Posts) all the posts, except one category. Is this possible? 
This is simple on wordpress but on blogger I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello @kiroeshima, please attach your blog template to help you, you might use pastepin.

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh, Hello, thank you very much!
https://pastebin.com/4Entk218 (part1) and 
https://pastebin.com/tnm3Lbap (part2)